# Twilio PHP - Running AJAX script once the call is completed

Tags: php, twilio

I'm building an IVR with Twilio and PHP. Once the call is completed, I need to run an AJAX function that sends session variables to an external server. I've tried to include the script at the end of my last PHP file but obviously, I get a parsing error because of the javascript code.

What would be the best way to run a javascript function (from my php file preferably) once the call is completed?

I've tried to run the file within the CallBack but it doesn't keep my session variables.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your code is all in PHP, surely you don't need an AJAX function. AJAX is for sending data from a web page in a browser. Can you send the data using PHP, not JavaScript? Or are you using Twilio Client for the call? Can you share the code you are using so far?

Comment: Hi Phil! The data has to be sent to another domain (URL). I didn't not know it was possible to send POST data to an external URL in PHP. Would you suggest cURL? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you use the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) to make API calls, that is making a POST request to an external URL. I would look into using curl, [this blog post is a good example](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).

Comment: Great, thanks for your explanations!

Comment: I left a more authoritative answer for anyone else that comes across this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't want to run a JavaScript function or need to perform any Ajax from your PHP as part of a server side webhook response. Ajax requests are for sending data from the client side in a browser with JavaScript and without refreshing the page.

Instead, if you need to send data to another server you can do so from PHP. The best way is likely with curl, there is a good example of how to use it in [this blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).